# error while importing data in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried to import data from a dump file on MySQL workbench 8, it is showing the (unknown database) error with code 1049 (42000)for each table in the database,
is it because I exported data from a different version of MySQL, is it an error with the folder (corrupted) or I have done something wrong in the process?

I choose Data import from server menu, then choose the dump folder and start importing then the error pop-up for every table, with 25 tables 25 errors.

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: *it is showing the (unknown database) error with code 1049 (42000)for each table in the database* I think you 1) do not specify `CREATE DATABASE` statement insertion during backup 2) do not create this database (and make it current) before restore.